# Reversed Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was assigned a problem in which I have to create a reversed Fibonacci sequence. It is meant to converge when the ratio is `-3.23607`. I am unsure why it won't output the `num` but I'm thinking it has something to do with my while loop. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void reverseFibonacci(int*, int*);


// Driver function 
int main()
{
int a, b;
int *ptr_1 = &a;
int *ptr_2 = &b;
cout << "what are points 1 and 2?" << endl;
cin >> *ptr_1 >> *ptr_2;
reverseFibonacci(ptr_1, ptr_2);
return 0;
}

void reverseFibonacci(int *a, int *b)
{
int *ptr1 = a;
int *ptr2 = b;
int c = *ptr1 - *ptr2;
int *ptr3 = &c;


int num = 0;


do
{
    *ptr3 = *ptr1-*ptr2;
    *ptr2 = *ptr1;
    *ptr1 = *ptr3;
    num++;
} while (((*ptr1 / *ptr2) + (*ptr2 / *ptr3)) >= -3.23607);

cout << num << endl;

int *q = new int[num];

for (int f = 0; f < num; f++)
{
    q[f] = *ptr1;
    q[f + 1] = *ptr2;
    c = *a - *b;
    *b = *a;
    *a = c;
}


for (int j = num - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
{
    cout << q[j] << " ";
}

delete[] q;
}
```

Comment: This question appears incomplete.  Which steps are confusing? What happens when you step through? What do you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: Doesn't compile.  Where is `n` declared?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code.
For example, in  the calculation (*ptr1 / *ptr2) + (*ptr2 / *ptr3)), you divide int, so you get int, not double as I guess you expected.

There were also some errors in term calculations (I assume that 'a' is the first term of the inverse series, forgive me if I am wrong).
For calculation of the q[] table, you only calculate q[0] and q[1]. I corrected it, assuming this q[] corresponds to the Fibonacci series in direct order.

I don't think it is necessary to use pointers to int instead of int. I modified it, but maybe it is not your choice.

I inserted writing of some intermediate values : I used them to correct the code. I let them to show you a possible way to debug a programme. 
I also used a vector instead of a C array. It will be easy for you to come back to the array if you need it. Besides that, I tried to follow your own code and not to modify everything.

As I may have modified the meaning of ptr1 and ptr2, please check that calculation of the convergence test ('ratio') is still correct.

Here is the code, seems to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void reverseFibonacci(int, int);
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cout << "what are points 1 and 2?" << endl;
    cin >> a >> b;
    reverseFibonacci(a, b);
    return 0;
}

void reverseFibonacci(int a, int b)
{
    const int num_max = 100;
    int ptr1 = a;
    int ptr2 = b;
    int ptr3;

    cout << "a = " << a << "\tb = " << b << "\n";
    int num = 0;
    double ratio;
    do
    {
        ptr3 = ptr1-ptr2;
        ptr1 = ptr2;
        ptr2 = ptr3;
        if ((ptr2 != 0) && (ptr3 != 0))
            ratio = static_cast<double> (ptr1) / ptr2 + static_cast<double>(ptr2) / ptr3;
        else
            ratio = -100.0; 
        cout << "num = " << num << "\t\tptr2 = " << ptr2 << "\t\tptr1 = " << ptr1 << "\t\tratio = " << ratio<< endl;
        num++;
    } while ((ratio >= -3.23607) && (num < num_max));

    cout << "num = " << num << endl;
    int n = num + 2;
    vector<int> q(n);
    for (int f = 0; f < n; f++)
    {
        q[f] = ptr2;
        ptr3 = ptr1 + ptr2;
        ptr2 = ptr1;
        ptr1 = ptr3;
    }
    cout << "Fibonacci series in direct order:\n";
    for (auto j : q) 
    {
        cout << j << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```